# C++ thread concurrency inside Class

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency

I am trying to run two concurrent threads inside a class, both of them printing out data using the same function. Using std::lock_guard for scoped locks.
the problem is that only the first thread is triggered. The second thread is never called

```
#include <thread>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>

//global 
std::mutex m_printmutex;

class Class
{
public:
    Class(const std::string& s, const int& i) : m_data(s), threadName(i) { }
    ~Class() { 
        m_thread.join(); 
        m_thread2.join();
        }
    void runThread() { 
        m_thread = std::thread(&Class::print, this); 
        m_thread2 = std::thread(&Class::print,this);
    }

private:
    std::string m_data;
    std::thread m_thread;
    std::thread m_thread2;
    int threadName;
    void print()  { 
        
        while(1){
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(m_printmutex);
            std::cout << "thread # " << std::this_thread::get_id() << " "  << m_data << '\n'; 
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
        }
        }
};

int main()
{
    Class c("Hello, world!",1);
    c.runThread();

}
```

as is evident from the the above example. thread joiing happends in the destructor.

the output of the programs is as follows:

```
thread # 140232348595776 Hello, world!
thread # 140232348595776 Hello, world!
thread # 140232348595776 Hello, world!
thread # 140232348595776 Hello, world!
thread # 140232348595776 Hello, world!
thread # 140232348595776 Hello, world!
thread # 140232348595776 Hello, world!
thread # 140232348595776 Hello, world!
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: The thread is sleeping whilst holding the lock.  When the thread wakes up (after the sleep) it unlocks the mutex and immediately retakes the lock.  `std::mutex` is not a fair mutex, if the code unlocks it and immediately tries to lock it again it will (almost certainly)  get the lock.  Try releasing the mutex before the sleep by introducing an additional local scope which contains just the lock_guard and the cout.

Comment: You say you are trying to run two "concurrent" threads, but it is not possible for them to make forward progress at the same time because neither can make forward progress without holding the one and only `m_printmutex` lock. In principle, each thread is trying to print an infinite number of times and they cannot both print at the same time, so you are trying to fairly divide an infinite quantity.

Answer (score 2):

```cpp
       while(1){
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(m_printmutex); 
            std::cout << "thread # " << std::this_thread::get_id() << " "  << m_data << '\n'; 
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
        } //mutex lock released here
```

The mutex is grabbed at the start of the loop iteration. It is held until the iteration ends and then it is immediately grabbed again, leaving a very small window for the other thread to sneak in and acquire the mutex.

Remove the sleep from the lock-protected block of code by inserting another code block:

```cpp
       while(1){
            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(m_printmutex); 
                std::cout << "thread # " << std::this_thread::get_id() << " "  << m_data << '\n'; 
            } // mutex lock released here
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
        }
```

This gives the other thread a whole second to get the mutex and do its work.

Note: you still aren't guaranteed a nice, orderly "1-thread 2-thread 1-thread 2-thread" sequence. Nothing prevents 2-thread from waking up and grabbing the mutex before 1-thread can, or vice-versa. If you want perfect ordering, look into `std::condition_variable`s.

Comment: Here is the following program with the changes and handling the condition variable waiting on a specific condition.